# pg_dump 9.2.x command does not work with pg_dump 9.2.3

Tags: postgresql

This is how i used to create all the time backups of my databases with PostgreSQL 9.2.x:

```
pg_dump -Fc -Z 6 -U postgres mydatabase > 2013-xx-xx_xxxxx.db
```

However on a machine where PostgreSQL with version 9.2.3 is running I get all the time the error "too many command line arguments" starting with "-Z". If I remove -Z he is complaining about "-U"?
What is wrong?

---

Okay there is definitely sth. wrong. I removed argument for argument until i just started pg_dump. Then i added argument by argument and it worked. So I opened another command line window and tried the same: First "too many arguments", after calling only "pg_dump" and adding further arguments it worked...

Comment: is machine with 9.2.3 is Mac?

Comment: what are the version of pg_dump's itself (pg_dump --version) on both machines?

Comment: It is a windows 64 bit machine with postgresql 9.2.3 64bit. I dont know what is wrong, seems like I have to call "pg_dump" without arguments first

Comment: Maybe there is an old `pg_dump` on the path. What does `pg_dump --version` show?

Answer (score 4):

I'd venture that it has nothing to with `pg_dump` version but that it may be an invisible spurious character on the command line that is causing this mess. As a demo, if I type this in `cmd.exe`, it works as expected at first:

> pg_dump -U postgres postgres >out.db

But now if I come back on this command with Arrow-Up, position the caret just before the `-U` option, add a non-breaking space by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd> on the numeric keypad, and validate this command, it yields the error you mention:

> pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "-U") Try "pg_dump
>   --help" for more information.

Comment: ... and in case you're wondering "I didn't type anything like that, what's this got to do with me": You could easily copy and paste such characters, particularly if you're copying from something like MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump --host <host> --port 5432 --username <login> --format custom --blobs --verbose --file /home/backup/databasename.backup databasename`

To run query without asking for password use `export PGPASSWORD=your_postgres_password` (linux) or `SET PGPASSWORD=your_postgres_password` (windows)

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  The command in the question seems perfectly legit.